# JSON to CSV export works in Chrome, not in IE

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

My goal is to simply grab a JSON and export it as a CSV file. Ideally the user gets a prompt within the web browser that asks whether to save or open the CSV file.

I came across many examples that require a call to the server for the JSON to Excel/CSV conversion but I do need a JavaScript-only solution. I found [**this particular fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hybrid13i/JXrwM/) useful.

This works just fine when it's run with Chrome (v39) but nothing happens in IE11. In fact, I see a couple of errors in IE's console as follows:

[image]

I'm still trying to figure out whether these errors are browser specific, which I think they are. And if so, if there's any workaround. As my target browser is IE, "But it works in Chrome so use it" won't do me any good. I've spent hours trying to find a workaround for this to no avail, so any pointer in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Below is verbatim copy and paste of the aforementioned fiddle:

**HTML**

```
<div class='mydiv'>    
    <textarea id="txt" class='txtarea'>
    [{"Vehicle":"BMW","Date":"30, Jul 2013 09:24 AM","Location":"Hauz Khas, Enclave, New Delhi, Delhi, India","Speed":42},{"Vehicle":"Honda CBR","Date":"30, Jul 2013 12:00 AM","Location":"Military Road,  West Bengal 734013,  India","Speed":0},{"Vehicle":"Supra","Date":"30, Jul 2013 07:53 AM","Location":"Sec-45, St. Angel's School, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","Speed":58},{"Vehicle":"Land Cruiser","Date":"30, Jul 2013 09:35 AM","Location":"DLF Phase I, Marble Market, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","Speed":83},{"Vehicle":"Suzuki Swift","Date":"30, Jul 2013 12:02 AM","Location":"Behind Central Bank RO, Ram Krishna Rd by-lane, Siliguri, West Bengal, India","Speed":0},{"Vehicle":"Honda Civic","Date":"30, Jul 2013 12:00 AM","Location":"Behind Central Bank RO, Ram Krishna Rd by-lane, Siliguri, West Bengal, India","Speed":0},{"Vehicle":"Honda Accord","Date":"30, Jul 2013 11:05 AM","Location":"DLF Phase IV, Super Mart 1, Gurgaon, Haryana, India","Speed":71}]
    </textarea>
    <button class='gen_btn'>Generate File</button>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var data = $('#txt').val();
        if(data == '')
            return;
        JSONToCSVConvertor(data, "Vehicle Report", true);
    });
});

function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) {
    //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
    var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

    var CSV = '';    
    //Set Report title in first row or line

    CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

    //This condition will generate the Label/Header
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = "";

        //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {
            //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
            row += index + ',';
        }
        row = row.slice(0, -1);

        //append Label row with line break
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    //1st loop is to extract each row
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";

        //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
        }
        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

        //add a line break after each row
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    if (CSV == '') {        
        alert("Invalid data");
        return;
    }   

    //Generate a file name
    var fileName = "MyReport_";
    //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g,"_");   

    //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
    var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

    // Now the little tricky part.
    // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
    // but this will not work in some browsers
    // or you will not get the correct file extension    

    //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
    var link = document.createElement("a");    
    link.href = uri;

    //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
    link.style = "visibility:hidden";
    link.download = fileName + ".csv";

    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Comment: I found a thread where a similar "permission denied" error was with iframe, maybe there'll be something relevant for you: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13936 (Got no IE on linux, so can't test, sorry :P)

Comment: @MightyPork - Unless there's some iframe that gets added by JSFiddle compiler at the runtime, I doubt the linked ticket is relevant to my case. And as you can see in the code, there's no use of iframe whatsoever.

Comment: I think it's got something to do with dynamically adding certain elements that IE thinks can be harmful. They solved it by changing the way the iframe is added, i think. Also maybe the autoclicking the link can be the cause..

Answer (score 1):

IE normal doesnt support download tribute. you have to try with blob method.
conver the Json to CSV then usning blob you can download from IE.

nb : this wont work in IE9 or less will work in IE10+
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45641408/8151001

Answer (score 0):

Are you hosting the jquery file or accessing it via a CDN? Try using Google's CDN.
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Here is where the code is generating the error.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Above example is from the JSFiddle so I suppose it is hosted. I don't think which CDN is being used matters but will give it a try.

Comment: It is a Microsoft security issue. IE11 is blocking the script because it is from another host. If you click on the SCRIPT5 in the error log it takes you to the MSDN page. See MSDN for the solution. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn887953(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Jeremiah, if what you said holds true, this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/j9q1qghf/) should throw an error as well (for simply referencing the jQuery) but it doesn't. How's this any different from the above example?

Comment: The code is getting an error that jQuery says to see the ticket MightyPork referenced. I posted the picture above. Try running the code on your local machine.

Comment: The html, css, and javascript. Create your own html file. Run it in your local machine. You'll need to download the jquery or link to it.

Comment: Jeremiah, thanks for taking time to adding comments but I'd rather you stay within the scope of this problem. This has to do with the aforementioned fiddle I added. Clearly the code works in Chrome but not in IE and I need to figure out why. Is the Fiddle error indeed caused by IE11 blocking the script as you stated? Why does one work and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to IE not supporting Data URIs to export CSV files:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The other browsers do. I know this is an old question. I hope you have found a work around in the past few months?