# JSON to CSV / XLS does not save a file on IE

Tags: javascript, json, export

I have the following service:

```
angular.module('LBTable').service('exportTable', function () {
    function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel, fileName) {
        //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
        var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

        var CSV = '';
        //Set Report title in first row or line

        //CSV += ReportTitle + '\r\n\n';

        //This condition will generate the Label/Header
        if (ShowLabel) {
            var row = "";

            //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
            for (var index in arrData[0]) {

                //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
                row += index + ',';
            }

            row = row.slice(0, -1);

            //append Label row with line break
            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }

        //1st loop is to extract each row
        for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
            var row = "";

            //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
            for (var index in arrData[i]) {
                row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
            }

            row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

            //add a line break after each row
            CSV += row + '\r\n';
        }

        if (CSV == '') {
            alert("Invalid data");
            return;
        }

        //Generate a file name
        fileName = (fileName != null ? fileName : 'Report');
        //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
        fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g, "_");

        //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
        var uri = 'data:text/xls;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);

        // Now the little tricky part.
        // you can use either>> window.open(uri);
        // but this will not work in some browsers
        // or you will not get the correct file extension

        //this trick will generate a temp <a /> tag
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = uri;

        //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
        link.style = "visibility:hidden";
        link.download = fileName + ".xls";

        //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }

    return {
        exportCSV: JSONToCSVConvertor
    }
});
```

Basicly what this does is to take a `JSON` object and converts it into a csv file that is then downloaded by the user

this works fine in Chrome and Firefox however in IE (even the newest) no file is downloaded and the console does not throw any errors.

My question is why? :(

(simplified fiddle)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s1w4py1f/)

Answer (score 1):

the Reason is IE doesn't support the download attribute in a tag. The work around is you can Use blob

1. Convert the JSON to CSV
2. Check the current browser for that you can use the below code

> ```
>  getInternetExplorerVersion() {
>             var rv = -1;
>             if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
>                 var ua = navigator.userAgent;
>                 var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
>                 if (re.exec(ua) != null)
>                     rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
>             }
>             else if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
>                 var ua = navigator.userAgent;
>                 var re = new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
>                 if (re.exec(ua) != null)
>                     rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
>             }
>             return rv;
>         }
> ```

3. if the browser is IE

> ```
> var blob = new Blob([CSV], { type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8;" });
> navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName + ".csv")
> ```

This will work in IE